# Extract Chain of EMail Text into multiple rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, regex

I have a `pandas Dataframe`

| MessageID | Actual Email |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Below |
| 2 | Below |

The value in Actual Email column looks like this:

"From: Sales, Team sales@abc.com
Sent: Monday, April 10, 2023 2:36 PM
To: customer,1 customer1@client.com
Subject: Some Message

Hello Customer1,

Welcome and thank you for opting in to receive emails from us

Sincerely,
Some Name

On Tue, Apr 11, 2023 at 8:13?AM Important Customer customer1@client.com
wrote:

Thanks Sales!
-Customer1

"

I need to split the *From Message* and *Reply Message* into two separate rows, which is shown below:

| MessageID | Actual Email |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Hello Customer1,Welcome and thank you for opting in to receive emails from us |
| 1 | Thanks Sales! -Customer1 |

I tried using `Splitlines()` function, but that didn't work.

Thanks in advance for any support in solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) :

```
import re

splits = (df.pop("Actual Email")
              .str.extract(r"^.*Subject:.*?\n(?P<Message>.*)^On.*wrote:\n(?P<Reply>.*)",
                           flags=re.S|re.M).replace('[\n+"]', "", regex=True)
         )

tmp = pd.DataFrame(splits.to_numpy().reshape(-1,1),
                   index=splits.index.repeat(2), columns=["Actual Email"])
```

Output (*with two formats*) :
​

```
print(df.join(splits))

   MessageID                                                                                            Message                     Reply
0          1  Hello Customer1,Welcome and thank you for opting in to receive emails from usSincerely, Some Name  Thanks Sales! -Customer1​
```

---

```
print(df.join(tmp))


   MessageID                                                                                       Actual Email
0          1  Hello Customer1,Welcome and thank you for opting in to receive emails from usSincerely, Some Name
0          1                                                                           Thanks Sales! -Customer1
```

---

***Regex explanation:***

- `^` : start of a line
- `.*` : any character (*zero or more times*)
- `Subject:` : the literal string "Subject:"
- `.*?` : any character (*zero or more times*), but as few times as possible
- `\n` : new line character
- `(?P<Message>.*)` : any character (*zero or more times*) captured inside a named group "Message"
- `^On.*wrote:` : the literal string "On" followed by any character (*zero or more times*), followed by the literal string "wrote:"
- `\n` : a new line character
- `(?P<Reply>.*)` : any character (*zero or more times*) captured inside a  named group "Reply"

> *Regex* [[demo](https://regex101.com/r/FlQbh2/1)]

Comment: Would you pls explain regex part in Extract function? how this (?P<Message>.*) fetch body of the function?

Comment: I added to the answer an *explanation* and a [*demo*](https://regex101.com/r/FlQbh2/1) of the regex pattern.