Reading MIME body of email
Traditional Domino design...db is mail-in database and receives emails from outside our domain.   The resulting arrived memos are Multipart MIME-based emails.  The documentation of NotesMIMEEntity seems pretty detailed but very little in the way of explaining or examples, etc.
I simply need to read the body of an incoming email to scrape items that are ultimately used in an agent set to run against newly arrived emails.   The agent that does the scraping knows that the incoming email is bound by a template, so it knows what to find and retrieve.
How to get it is the problem.   This is all new to me, mime entities and sibling entites and multiparts and boundaries...I am hoping someone has examples or can point me to an article detailing how to read this content.  I just want the body as plain text.

For a general overview, maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48562935/what-are-the-parts-in-a-multipart-email/48563281#48563281

The Domino community if great.. just a pity the official documentation isn't! If you can use java in your project you can use the apache commons mime message parser

You can let Domino convert the MIME content to Rich Text and then read contents from the Rich Text field.
Try something like this (not tested):
Dim rtitem As NotesRichTextItem
Dim plainText As String

notesSession.ConvertMIME = false
Set rtitem = doc.GetFirstItem("Body")
plainText = rtitem.GetFormattedText( False, 0 )
notesSession.ConvertMIME = true


Henrik,
When exactly does the conversion to Rich Text occur?   It looks like your code sample you are instructing it to NOT convert at the very beginning, and then resetting it to True as you end it.
I do remember that Rich Text, when creating it newly, needs to be saved to the backed before the content is available...I don't know yet how that might afffect what I am trying to do.
Maybe that is out of habit you wrote it that way?  I will experiment with the seed of an idea you have given me though and report back.

Henrik, that was exactly what I needed, just getting the plain text so I can parse it out.   Thank you!

If you want to walk (recursively) through the MIME item using NotesMimeEntity objects, you can find an example here: LotusScript: Combine two NotesMIMEEntity objects
